# Defined function calling parse query always returns empty but parse returns sucessfully

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have defined a function which returns List of ParseUser, the function always returns emtpy list but parse returns successfully list, here's my code:

```
public static List<ParseUser> userFriends;

// The function takes the ParseUser and returns his/her friends from parse
public static List<ParseUser> getUserFriends(final ParseUser user) {
    userFriends = new ArrayList<ParseUser>();
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryFriends = ParseUser.getQuery();
    queryFriends.whereEqualTo("friendRelations", user);
    queryFriends.include("user");
    queryFriends.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> parseUsers, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // This works perfect, userFriends has the returned list
                userFriends = parseUsers;
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    // This always returns empty list, idk how userFriends doesn't have any value
    return userFriends;
}
```

I can't figure out how this function returns empty list yet.

Comment: the done callback might not be getting called until after you return userFriends?

Comment: I am not sure yet, but If I put Log.d before return userFriends, it says 0 size.

Comment: I would guess that is your issue. If you need to wait for done to be hit in the callback you could pass a listener and use it to handle listen for done to complete.

Comment: So why return userFriends is called before done?

Comment: done isn't a direct method that you are calling in sequence, it is part of a FindCallback class, meaning that when FindCallback hits it's done method, you will override it and update your userFriends. It is possible (and likely in this case) that done is being called after you return userFriends. So what is happening is you are returning userFriends (which is empty) and then at some point it is being updated in the done method, but after you have already returned your list.

Comment: You're right, Log.d always prints userFriends size before the done function.